# PHP simple html dom find all input[type=text] or there is no type

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to extract all the form inputs, which their `type` is `text`.

My problem is, at least in Chrome, that's an `input` tag, without the `type` attribute specified, is rendered as `text`.

How can I find all the tags which their `type` is no specified, or it's value is `text` with **simple html dom**?

My current:

```
foreach ($form->find('input[type=text]') as $input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you might have to do this:

```
foreach ($form->find('input') as $input){
  if($input->type==''||$input->type=='text'){
    //code
  }
}
```

Unless the parser can use this type of selector: `input[type=''],input[type=text]`

In JQuery, that would select all elements with either no type or type equals to text.

Answer (score 1):

Read this

[Grabbing hidden inputs as a string (Using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496220/grabbing-hidden-inputs-as-a-string-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser)

I am not sure but try this

```
$html->find('input[type=text]', 0);
```

Comment: Your example just picks the nth element. Anyway, I decided to just iterate the whole inputs and check for their type, if it's text, or if it's empty. Thanks for your help.