# Can't scrape value of a class (PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser)

Tags: php, parsing, dom, web-scraping

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = '<input class="questionData" type="hidden" value="abc@abc.gmail.com" />';
$html = str_get_html($html);

// get mail
foreach($html->find('.questionData') as $node) {
$found = $node->plaintext;
echo $found;
}

// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

Hi,

I'm trying to scrape the email out of the class(questionData).
I have no success to get the email, but when i try the same code with an other class it works. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Try: $found = $node->value;

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get hidden input tag value as string using PHP simple HTML DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326691/get-hidden-input-tag-value-as-string-using-php-simple-html-dom)